# Black screenshots on elementary OS Freya x64 with AMD graphics drivers

Tags: release-freya, graphic-drivers, screenshot

Since I installed Freya on my PC every screenshot I take using 'print screen' key is black. I also tried using 'import' command with different options, but it only made opened windows visible on the images and my desktop was black. I had the newest AMD drivers installed from AMD website. My graphics card is Radeon R7 250x. The only solution I found on the internet was to [upgrade kernel to new version and install AMD open source drivers](https://allienworks.net/2015/elementary-os-freya-amd-drivers/) and I updated kernel to 3.17 and installed the drivers, but it didn't help. I tried upgrading to kernel 4.0 and 4.1, but then I got black screen after boot. So now I'm using kernel 3.17 and AMD open source drivers and I still have this issue - all my screenshots appear black.

PS My display is not recognized by the system. Could this be the cause?

Comment: Same problem with AMD A8-4500M and fglrx

Answer (score 3):

First, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and then take a screenshot.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is being down-voted, since it is a valid workaround for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical problem for AMD proprietary drivers. For it can not affect anybody, except AMD. Only one way out - use default free driver.

Comment: When do we need the AMD proprietary driver? Is there any different when we are using it?

Comment: @JulianLai Less power consumption , better performance and no overheating

Comment: The free driver is very good in kernel 4.4 and 4.5 . I am going to try it since fglrx has lots of problems